Need to write sharepoint list column validation to ensure step by step status updates
I have a status column in a SharePoint list. I need to write validation to make sure when the admin updates the status column, that the statuses are entered and updated in order. The correct order for all entries should be " not started" -> " In Work" -> "Complete". Also if the "Request type" column = material site transfer and "To location" column = Siler city the order should be " not started" -> " In Work" -> " in transit" ->"Complete" but only for entries with that criteria. Any help would be appreciated, Im not savvy with coding
Ive tried a couple different formulas but to no avail. This was the most recent attempt.
=IF(AND([Request type]="Material Site Transfer", [To location]="Siler City"), IF(OR( AND([Status]="Not started"), AND([Status]="In work"), AND([Status]="In transit"), AND([Status]="Complete") ), TRUE, FALSE), IF(OR( AND([Status]="Not started"), AND([Status]="In work"), AND([Status]="Complete") ), TRUE, FALSE) )

I don't think you will be able to check the previous column value in list validation formula to enforce the status change in specific order.
